# Correctly decoding/encoding raw PCM data

Tags: audio, frequency, wave, resampling

I'm writing my WAVE decoder/encoder in C++. I've managed to correctly convert between different sample sizes (8, 16 and 32), but I need some help with the channels and the frequency.

**Channels:**

If I want to convert from stereo to mono:

1. do I just take the data from one channel (which one? 1 or 2?)?
2. or do I take the average from channel 1 and 2 for the mono channel.

If I want to convert from mono to stereo:
(I know this is not very scientific)

1. can I simply add the samples from the single channels into both the stereo channels?
2. is there a more scientific method to do this (eg: interpolation)?

**Sample rate:**

How do I change the sample rate (resample), eg: from 44100 Hz to 22050 Hz:

1. do I simply take the average of 2 sequential samples for the new (lower frequency) value?
2. Any more scientific algorithms for this?

Comment: Question is better suited to http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I assume you mean 44100 Hz to 22050 Hz ?

Comment: For future reference you can always hit the `| edit |` link above and fix typos and other mistakes in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Stereo to mono - take the mean of the left and right samples, i.e. `M = (L + R) / 2` - this works for the vast majority of stereo content, but note that there are some rare cases where you can get left/right cancellation.
- Mono to stereo - put the mono sample in both left and right channels, i.e. `L = R = M` - this gives a sound image which is centered when played as stereo
- Resampling - for a simple integer ratio downsampling as in your example above, the process is:

  - low pass filter to accommodate new Nyquist frequency, e.g. 10 kHz LPF for 22.05 kHz sample rate
  - decimate by required ratio (i.e. drop alternate samples for your 2x downsampling example)

Note that there are third party libraries such as [libsamplerate](http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/) which can handle resampling for you in the general case, so if you have more than one ratio you need to support, or you have some tricky non-integer ratio, then this might be a better approach